# How to merge deleted/changed file in eGit

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, git-merge, egit

The case:

Locally, I have a commit where I have deleted a file. Remotely, someone else have changed this file.

Now, when I merge, I find that git has the put the changed file in my working tree. This is probably the way git works, and in `git` command line, I'd be able to use `git mergetool` to choose between the deleted or changed file.

In eGit, however, how would I make this choice?

We ended up with a *quite unusable* work-around where we first addded the file to the index and then deleted it in working tree and then saved this change (deletion) to the index.

Technical info:

The version of eGit (feature) we're using is `4.9.2.201712150930-r`.

The version of git we're using is `2.16.1`

Background:

My team have recently moved to using Git as our revision control system. There's a general wish from team members to use an integrated solution and since we're working with Eclipse, eGit seemed to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that all your team members follow this process:

1. Commit your changes to your local repository.
2. Pull with rebase to merge with the remote origin branch.
3. Resolve the conflicts, if any. In your case, if you deleted the file before the other team member modified it, then that person would have noticed that the file has been deleted.
4. Push the commit upstream.

This process has worked for us. Hope this helps.